# How to change index position in array push

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to change the index position in array push on json
Below is my output:

```
{
"MINIMUM": [{
    "HCB-6": {
        "min": "3.6"
    }
}]
```

}

Using this code:

```
$driver_id=$res->driver_id;
$get_distance=str_replace(',','.',$dist);
$distance[$req_latpl] = array();
$distance[$driver_id] = array();
array_push($distance[$req_latpl], $driver_id);
$drivers[$req_latpl]['min'] = min($distance[$req_latpl]);
```

How can i change the code to achieve the below output:

```
{
"MINIMUM": [{
    "min": "3.6",
    "driverid": "HCB-6"
}]
```

}

thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Desired JSON is not valid.

Comment: you cannot have duplicate keys(min), names/keys should be unique.

Comment: No, it is not. Check it on http://jsonlint.com/ Maybe you want something like `{ "MINIMUM": [ { "min": {...} }, { "min": {...} } ] }` ?

Comment: Please use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to manipulate your json data, not str_replace

Comment: How does your starting data look?

Comment: is it okey all guys..!!

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

First decode the json string. Modify it to desired format and encode it back to json string. Try the below code

```
// sample json string
$main_data = '{
"MINIMUM": [{
    "HCB-6": {
        "min": "3.6"
    }
}]
}';
// decode json string
$main_data_decode = json_decode($main_data);
// generate required data
foreach($main_data_decode->MINIMUM[0] as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        $modified_data->MINIMUM[0]->min = $v; 
    }
    $modified_data->MINIMUM[0]->driverid =  $key;
}
// encode data to json string
$modified_data_encode = json_encode($modified_data);
echo $modified_data_encode;
```

Output:
    {"MINIMUM":[{"min":"3.6","driverid":"HCB-6"}]}

Considering the Keys to be remain same in the json string and format too.